# The zero morphism lifts to a zero homotopic complex morphism.

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

There is something I don't understand in the proof I am reading from a book. The book is called Algebra and application, Alexander Zimmermann-Representation theory homological algebra point of view. What I don't understand from the proof is that how do we get the below formula[image]

$$\alpha_1 = h_0 \circ d_1 + e_2 \circ h_1$$

Answer (score 0):

By the computation $e_1\gamma_1 = 0$, we know that $\gamma_1$ factors through the inclusion $C_2 \to Q_1$; this is just a fancy way of saying that the image of $\gamma_1$ lies in the kernel of $e_1$, so that we can restrict the codomain of $\gamma_1$ to obtain $\gamma_1:P_1 \to C_2$. Now since $Q_2$ is projective and $e_2:Q_2 \to C_2$ is an epimorphism, we can lift $\gamma_1$ to a map $h_1:P_1 \to Q_2$ satisfying $e_2h_1=\gamma_1$; but by definition $\gamma_1 = \alpha_1 - h_0d_1$, so we conclude that $ e_2h_1 = \alpha_1 - h_0d_1$, i.e.,

$$\alpha_1 = h_0d_1 + e_2h_1.$$
Continuing this way we obtain a chain map $\alpha_n$ that is null-homotopic.